# How to use Simple mobile redirect module

Tags: 7, theming

I am in a fix and not sure how to use the simple mobile redirect module. I am using Drupal 7 site which has a separate domain for its mobile version. I would like to redirect the user(accessing from mobile) to m.sitename.com. When i use my opera mini in my mobile to access the site, i am redirected to the mobile version of my site. But when i again try to access the site, it redirects to sitename.com instead of m.sitename.com. When i clear my mobile browser caches it works fine. Is there any way by which i can clear the cache automatically and redirect the user to the mobile version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could try using [Mobile switch](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_switch) module instead. Here is the [tutorial](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode52)

Comment: Thanks for your reply indrock. Before trying i would like to say that i am redirecting the user to a different 3rd party site. I think mobile switch allows only theme switching!

Comment: yes, it is used to switch theme based on various rules! It will not be useful if you are redirecting to some site, which happens to be the case ;-)

Comment: Consider SEO Duplicate content issues when you are dealing with multi domains for the same contents. There are lots of do and do not do issues you have to deal with, for example make sure the redirected to domain only can be accessed by certain devices type or browser name or any mechanism that detect the user device and or browser. Also you may double secure it with deny indexing for the sub domain.

Comment: i suggested you use Responsive design instead of different versions for your website.